# OnClick and OnClientClick with Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net website.On this,I want to start a stopwatch from javascript code after a button click. The button click also has to call server.

So what I did is in OnClick event, it will call server and do the task it has to do and then using hiddenfield I will load the javascript which will start the stopwatch.

This was working fine till I was not downloading file.

For example:
This is my OnClick function code

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "StartStopWatch();", true);
        //UpdateOpenerHiddenField.Value = "true";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.zip");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/folder/abc.zip"));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();


    }
```

Now the code doesnt work. If I remove attachment download code, this works fine.
My stopwatch javascript function name is StartStopWatch()
How should i fix this?

Comment: What? What is your code suppose to do?

Comment: execute after Response.end

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that is:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "StartStopWatch();", true);
```

Is being erased by this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I wanted any workaround for this problem. Found the solution which is posted above.